# Is there a system of mathematics where $4>2$ is false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, integers, axioms, number-comparison

A recent [question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/72742/24339) on propositional logic posted on Philosophy Stack Exchange yielded an [answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/72743/24339) which states, in part, that,

> The fact that $4$ is greater than $2$ is not a "logical fact" but and [sic] arithmetical one: it depends on the axioms of arithmetic.

The context of the question was a cited proposition from a book on logic for which the author claims that knowing that a creature has four legs is not enough to prove that it has more than two legs.

Is there a set of mathematical axioms or form of mathematics in which $4>2$ is meaningful but false?

Some commenters mentioned the possibility of modular (modulo) arithmetic, but admitted that $4>2$ in those systems would either be true or meaningless.

Comment: It's easy enough to prove that in a totally ordered ring, 0 < 1 has to be true, and hence 2 < 4. I suspect it's the case that if 0 and 1 are comparable then 0 < 1, but I haven't actually proved it. Anyway, if you want < to have its usual meaning as indicating a transitive irreflexive total relation, and you want 1 to have its usual meaning as "a multiplicative identity in a ring", and you want < to respect addition and multiplication, then 2 < 4 has to be true.

Comment: Well, the question is what you mean by "system of mathematics".  You can certainly make whatever crazy definitions or axioms you want so that $4>2$ is true (by just completely changing the meanings of the symbols 4, >, and 2).  Whether there is such a system that is "natural" is a rather different (and vague) question.  To be clear, the answer you are referring to was talking about the first case, not the second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a "model" for which this assertion is true, **in a weaker sense** ; in the framework of 2-adic numbers (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html), we have :

$$\underbrace{|4|_2}_{1/2^2=1/4} < \ \  \  \underbrace{|2|_2}_{1/2}$$

where $| \cdots|_2$ is the 2-adic "valuation", which is a kind of absolute value, or norm.

Explanation : this norm on integers is based on the (unique) prime factor decomposition of any integer .

Let us take an example ; consider $360$ ; as it is decomposed into

$$360=2^3 \times 3^2 \times 5$$

the $2$-adic norm is obtained by inverting the first factor (containing the power of $2$) :

$$|360|_2=\dfrac{1}{2^3}=\dfrac{1}{8}$$

"The more a number is divisible by $2$, the smaller it is for this norm".

This norm and the associated distance verify the distance axioms, but in an almost paradoxical way where triangle inequality

$$d(x,z) \le d(x,y)+d(y,z) \ \ \text{is a consequence of} \ \ d(x,z) \le \max(d(x,y),d(y,z))$$

which is much stricter condition  ("ultrametric distance").

Remarks :

1) p-adic numbers have played a rôle in the proof or Fermat's last theorem, as well as for a recent Field medalist : see the nice article [here](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/the-numbers-behind-a-fields-medalists-math/)

2) A brief and accurate account on the discovery of $p$-adic numbers in general (p any prime number, not especially $2$) and the difficulty to give them a rigorous status in the 1900/1940s is given [here](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~panchish/Mag2009L3/GouveaHensel2.pdf).

Comment: +1. To the OP, note that this is more than just a model - it's an **interesting** model! It's easy to whip up an artificial model of the relevant statement, but this is one that's actually mathematically important.

Comment: But this is $|4|_2 < |2|_2$, which is not the same as $4 < 2$, even if $4$ and $2$ are regarded as $2$-adic numbers.  The $2$-adic numbers are not ordered, so the statement $4 > 2$ is meaningless in the $2$-adic setting.  Your statement is akin to the assertion that $-1 > 0$ because $|-1| > |0|$, where $0,-1\in\mathbb{R}$ and $|\cdot|$ denotes the usual absolute value.

Comment: @Xander Henderson : all right, I should have said it, but I haven't made an error, I haven't said 4 < 2. I know that it is not an ordered structure (I have been working a time on adeles and ideles in the book "Number Theory" of André Weil). The elements are comparable in the much weaker terms of their "size" , had the word a meaning in this context. I think I have answered in the spirit of the question which, seemingly, is : can we find a context in which "ordering" (in a wide sense, OK) is counterintuitive.

Comment: So, just to be clear, if the question were "Is there a set of mathematical axioms or form of mathematics in which $-1 > 0$ is meaningful but false?", you would answer "Yes.  Observe that $\lvert -1 \rvert > |0|$?"

Comment: @Xander Henderson I don't want to polemicate. I think my answer is "as it is" with a "disclaimer" in bold letters right at the beginning  ; it has, besides, the small interest to spread the information about the existence of these pure mathematical jewels $\mathbb{Z_p}$ and $\mathbb{Q_p}$ (and all the mathematical objects that one can build out of them) constructed by a "tour de force"  combining abstract algebraic and topological tools.

Comment: The question was originally asked in the context of a discussion of *logic*.  The precise meaning of the symbols matters.  In the $p$-adic numbers, however beautiful or interesting they are, the statement $4 > 2$ is meaningless.  It is akin to the statement that $i > 0$ because $|i|=1> 0$.